# Why next('route') doesn't work correctly?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to do simple things with express and can't handle this simple situation .

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const router = express.Router()

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (true) return next('route')
  next()
})

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('next router')
  res.send('hello, user!')
})

app.use('/admin', router, function (req, res) {
  console.log('next appppppp')
  res.sendStatus(401)
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is runing on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

As you can see in `router.use` i check ifits true , then go to `next('route')` and in the express docs ,as i understood , it have to check `router.get` , but actually it checks only `app.use` . 
So what's the problem ? Yes i understand that code works right , because i took it right from the documentation page , buti misunderstood this situation . So can anyone describe me whats happening here ?

Comment: Per [the docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html): *"`next('route')` will work only in middleware functions that were loaded by using the `app.METHOD()` or `router.METHOD()` functions."*

Comment: `router.use(function (req, res, next) {
next('route')
}, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('1')
  next()
}
)

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('next router')
  res.send('hello, user!')
})`

So why in this case it also console '1' then 'next router' ?